# Two keypresses processed in each frame (pygame snake game)

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a snake game, and I want to make sure that if you want to turn twice (for example a 180 degree turn), if both keys are pressed in the same frame, the next key press will be processed in the next frame, so that the snake actually turns twice over two frames instead of changing direction twice in the same frame, which could cause it to turn into itself and die. So basically, one turn per frame.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
import keyboard
import random
import time

class body:
    def __init__(self,properties=[0,0,20,20],colour=-1):
        self.properties=properties
        self.colour=colour
        self.next=None

class fruit:
    def __init__(self,centre=[0,0],size=10):
        self.centre=centre
        self.size=size

def drawSnake(window,snake):
    pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,0,0),snake.properties)
    snake.colour=snake.colour*-1
    temp=snake.next
    while temp:
        # Alternate snake colour
        if temp.colour==-1:
            colour=(0,150,0)
        else:
            colour=(0,100,0)
        temp.colour=temp.colour*-1
        pygame.draw.rect(window,colour,temp.properties)
        temp=temp.next
    return snake

def drawApple(window,snake,size):
    numApples=500/(size*2)
    bound=numApples-1
    apple=fruit([(random.randint(0,bound)*(500/numApples))+size,(random.randint(0,bound)*(500/numApples))+size],size)
    #apple=fruit([290,250],10)
    pygame.draw.circle(window,"red",apple.centre,apple.size)
    return apple

def newGame():
    # Draw initial snake and apple
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    snake=body([240,240,20,20],-1)
    snake=drawSnake(window,snake)
    apple=drawApple(window,snake,10)
    return snake,apple

def die(snake):
    pygame.draw.rect(window,(180,0,0),[snake.properties[0],snake.properties[1],snake.properties[2],snake.properties[3]])
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(1)

def getDirection(key,direction):
    print(key)
    if key == pygame.K_w:
        if direction!=[0,20]:
            direction=[0,-20]
    if key == pygame.K_a:
        if direction!=[20,0]:
            direction=[-20,0]
    if key == pygame.K_s:
        if direction!=[0,-20]:
            direction=[0,20]
    if key == pygame.K_d:
        if direction!=[-20,0]:
            direction=[20,0]
    return direction

def move(snake,apple,direction,length):
    # New body piece location
    x=snake.properties[0]+direction[0]
    y=snake.properties[1]+direction[1]
    # If snake crashed, restart
    if x<0 or y<0 or x>480 or y>480:
        die(snake)
        snake,apple=newGame()
        return snake,apple,0,False
    # Check if collision with body
    temp=snake
    # Create new body piece with other colour and add to front of list
    newBody=body([x,y,20,20],snake.colour*-1)
    newBody.next=snake
    snake=newBody
    # If apple is eaten
    if [x,y]==[apple.centre[0]-10,apple.centre[1]-10]:
        # Add 1 to length, spawn new apple, do not remove end body piece
        length+=1
        apple=drawApple(window,snake,10)
        while temp:
            # Check if apple spawned in body
            if temp.properties[0]==apple.centre[0]-10 and temp.properties[1]==apple.centre[1]-10:
                apple=drawApple(window,snake,10)
                temp=snake.next
            temp=temp.next
    else:
        # Remove end body piece
        temp=snake
        while temp.next:
            # Check if collision with body
            if temp.next.properties[0]==x and temp.next.properties[1]==y:
                die(snake)
                snake,apple=newGame()
                return snake,apple,0,False
            previous=temp
            temp=temp.next
        pygame.draw.rect(window,"white",temp.properties)
        previous.next=None
    return snake,apple,length,True

# Make window
pygame.init()
window=pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

snake,apple=newGame()
length=0
delay=0.1
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.update()
prevEvents=[]

while True:
    # Wait until a key is pressed to start the game
    pressed_keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Key is pressed, get direction and start main game loop
            direction=getDirection(event.key,[])
            game=True
            ## MAIN GAME LOOP
            while game:
                # Set FPS
                clock.tick(1)
                # Get current event queue
                events=pygame.event.get()
                print("events1: ",events)
                print()
                # Add current event queue to previous events which were not processed as a key was pressed in the last frame
                prevEvents.extend(events)
                events=prevEvents
                prevEvents=[]
                print("events2: ",events)
                print()
                if events!=None:
                    i=1
                    for event in events:
                        if event.type == QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            # Key was pressed, get new direction of snake
                            direction=getDirection(event.key,direction)
                            # Save rest of event queue for next frame to process
                            prevEvents=events[i:len(events)+1]
                            print("prevEvents: ",prevEvents)
                            print()
                            # Make events nothing to exit this loop, move the snake and get to the next frame
                            events=[]
                            i+=1
                # Move and draw snake
                snake,apple,length,game=move(snake,apple,direction,length)
                snake=drawSnake(window,snake)
                pygame.display.update()
```

I am new to pygame, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: you could force a frame draw after each key event. Or, move key events into a separate queue and one process 1 per frame.

Comment: Moving them into a separate queue worked amazing thanks so much! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the keys pressed in a queue:

```py
direction_queue = []
```

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
        direction_queue.append('L')
    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        direction_queue.append('R')
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        direction_queue.append('U')
    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
        direction_queue.append('D')
```

Process the keys one after the other in the application loop:

```py
if direction_queue:
    direction = direction_queue[0]
    direction_queue.pop(0)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

COLUMNS, ROWS, TIESIZE = 20, 20, 20
window = pygame.display.set_mode((COLUMNS*TIESIZE, ROWS*TIESIZE))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

snake_x, snake_y = 9, 9
key_map = {pygame.K_a: 'L', pygame.K_d: 'R', pygame.K_w: 'U', pygame.K_s: 'D'}
direction_map = {'L': (-1, 0), 'R': (1, 0), 'U': (0, -1), 'D': (0, 1)}
direction_queue = []
direction = 'R'

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(5)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in key_map:
               direction_queue.append(key_map[event.key])

    text_surf = font.render(str(direction_queue), True, 'black')
    if direction_queue:
        direction = direction_queue[0]
        direction_queue.pop(0)
    snake_x = (snake_x + direction_map[direction][0]) % COLUMNS
    snake_y = (snake_y + direction_map[direction][1]) % ROWS

    window.fill("white")
    for c in range (1, COLUMNS):
        pygame.draw.line(window, "gray", (c*TIESIZE, 0), (c*TIESIZE, window.get_height()))
    for r in range (1, ROWS):
        pygame.draw.line(window, "gray", (0, r*TIESIZE), (window.get_width(), r*TIESIZE))
    rect = pygame.Rect(snake_x*TIESIZE, snake_y*TIESIZE, TIESIZE, TIESIZE)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, "red", rect)
    window.blit(text_surf, (10, 340))
    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: This actually helped so much, I tried doing it myself, but it was so slow and basically didn't work - it also showed me how to make the gridlines as well which I had no clue how to do. Thanks so much! 